# Disambiguating and controlling access to public, internal and hybrid gRPC APIs

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, api-design

I currently have a mobile application talks to a GraphQL API service which terminates SSL and then proxies requests to gRPC services. The gRPC services only talk to each other via gRPC.

This system works okay but writing all of the boilerplate to plumb the gRPC APIs through the GraphQL layer to the client is tedious and can be error prone.

I’ve started exploring the idea of talking directly to the backend via gRPC as the tooling has improved substantially over the last few years.

One issue I’m still wondering about, though, is the best way to disambiguate APIs only meant to be called internally by other services from those callable publicly by the native client.

There is also a third category, “hybrid” APIs where it can be called either internally or externally.

Examples —-

Internal: Sending an SMS via Twilio

Public: Log in to account

Hybrid: Update whether an inbox item is read (both from the app when opening a conversation and on the backend when a message is sent)

One option I thought of was an  interceptor that passes along a context to indicate if the request is internal or public and use this in the code to return an error or perform additional validation on public requests.

Another option is creating an API service which is still gRPC but fulfills the same purpose as the GraphQL API service.

A third option is disambiguating public and internal services at an organizational level which might require duplicating some APIs that exist for both.

Are there other options I’m unaware of? How have you tackled this issue?

Comment: Non coding (e.g. architectural) questions are discouraged on Stack Overflow. One way to solve your public|private partition is to add token-based [auth](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/) to your (non-public) gRPC requests. You can then add e.g. server interceptors to auth(N|Z) the requests. I have gRPC services deployed to Google Cloud Run and I use [Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/about-grpc) w/ [Firebase Auth](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/authentication-method) to authenticate requests w/ some of my own code to authorize.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I was thinking of doing something similar. Google Cloud Run is very interesting to me because it runs containers, scales to 0 and supports gRPC over HTTP/2.

Comment: You're welcome! Cloud Endpoints and Firebase Auth wasn't the easiest path and I'm very familiar with Google Cloud and gRPC. But, once you've navigated it successfully, it's reliable. Good luck!